# Are repeating points in Delaunay possible?

Tags: scipy, delaunay

I am using `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` to generate a triangulated mesh from a series of 3d points. Can I have repeating x,y data points that have differing z values?

I am noticing that right now it doesn't allow/adhere to this - see below example. Is there a setting that can allow this?

I wish to create a mesh that looks like a 'step', ie, like the below:

[image]

In order to achieve this mesh, there will be duplicate x,y points - 2 repeating points at `(0.5,0)` and also at `(0.5,1)`.

The following produces an incorrect mesh:

```
points = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,1], [1,0], [0.5,0], [0.5,0], [0.5,1], [0.5,1]])
z = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1])

tri = Delaunay(points)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(points[:,0], points[:,1], z, triangles=tri.simplices, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I can get it to work if I use different/non-repeating points:

```
points = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,1], [1,0], [0.5,0], [0.51,0], [0.5,1], [0.51,1]])
```